# How do I return a unique list based on JSON results in PHP?

Tags: php, json, unique

I’m attempting to use the values from one JSON link to populate values in other JSON links resulting in a unique list of values from the combined JSON.  I’ve gotten as far as creating the complete list of values, but I’m having a difficult time finding the syntax in the final loop to display only the unique values.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
$collection_string = file_get_contents("http://some_json_url.com/json");
$collection_list = json_decode($collection_string, true);

foreach ($collection_list as $col_lists => $col_list) {
     $object_string = file_get_contents('http://another_json_url.com/'.$col_list['key'].'/json');
     $object_list = json_decode($object_string, true);
     $object_array = array();

     foreach ($object_list as $objects => $object) {
          $object_array [] = array_unique($object); //Returns "Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in..."
          echo '<li><a href="some_search_url/'.$object_array.'/search/">'.$object_array.'</a></li>'; //Returns "Array"
          echo '<li><a href="some_search_url/'.$object.'/search/">'.$object.'</a></li>'; //Returns complete list
     }

}
```

Working code:

```
$collection_string = file_get_contents("http://some_json_url.com/json");
$collection_list = json_decode($collection_string, true);

$object_array = array();

foreach ($collection_list as $col_lists => $col_list) {
     $object_string = file_get_contents('http://another_json_url.com/'.$col_list['key'].'/json');
     $object_list = json_decode($object_string, true);

     foreach ($object_list as $key => $value) {
          array_push($object_array, $value);
     }
}

$object_unique = array_unique($object_array);
natcasesort($object_unique);

foreach ($object_unique as $key => $value) {
     echo '<li><a href="some_search_url/'.$value.'/search/">'.$value.'</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change this

```
$object_array [] = array_unique($object);
```

to that

```
$object_array [] = $object; // edited !
array_unique($object_array);
```

Maybe you can also do this with one line of code, but I dont know how to write it. But the way the way I wrote it it's a little bit unoptimized, it would be better to simply do the array_unique() only one time, right after the final loop.

Btw your problem is/was that you tried to make $object unique, which is not an array. it's a string/object.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the following: "Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given...on line 42
Array" (Repeat)

Comment: I just found an error and edited my post. please have a look ! you will have to delete "your" array_unique.

Comment: The edit took care of the error I was seeing.  
The response is now "ArrayArrayArray..." rather than the values of each Array, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: var_dump($object_array); returns "array(1) { [0]=> string(5) "image" } array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "image" [1]=> string(5) "sound" } array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "image" [1]=> string(5) "still" }..."  I'm hoping to echo "image sound still" rather than "Array Array Array" -Thanks

Comment: you cannot simply echo and array ! you need to loop through it, like `foreach ($array as $element) { echo $element; }`

Comment: I posted the working code above.  There's probably a more elegant solution, but this works. Thanks for your help!